# How do I call Python scripts from within a Python script such that the hierarchy information is always retained?

Tags: python, ipython

I'd like to run a few scripts within a script such that

1. Know when a script is being called from another script and when it's run directly
2. Be able to get information/variables from the parent script into the child script.

Here's an illustration of what I mean. Say I have files `mwe1.py` and `mwe2.py` with only one line of code:

```py
print(__name__)
```

And say I have another script (`mwe0.py`) with:

```py
print(__name__)
exec(open("mwe1.py").read())
exec(open("mwe2.py").read())
```

If I run `mwe0.py` all the code runs, but the hierarchy isn't preserved and (I think) I have no way of knowing from within `mwe1.py` that it was called by another script:

```py
In [4]: %run mwe0.py
__main__
__main__
__main__
```

But maybe there's a better way to get hierarchy information than just `__main__`? Is there a way to do what I want?

Comment: The second run doesn't repeat all of the prints only because they're already loaded into memory, stored in the module cache.

Comment: "the right command to do that" To do *what*? If you want to get a list of dependencies, there are plenty of tools already available that parse your Python files transitively for `import`s without having to run them. What is the objective here?

Comment: @SilvioMayolo The objective is to run scripts within scripts retaining the two characteristics that I listed at the very bottom (in hindsight, I should have put them at the beginning). Maybe I'll make that edit

Comment: Scripts are only run the first time they're imported. You shouldn't design libraries so that the top-level code needs to be run multiple times.

Comment: `import` doesn't run a script. It imports a module, possibly with side effects. When you "run" a script in Python, it is, by definition, the `__main__` module, which is why `__name__` is `"__main__"` when you do so. Scripts don't have names like modules do.

Comment: In general, a module should just define functions and variables. The top-level code just initializes the variables. If you need something to be done multiple times, put it in a function that the importer calls when they need it.

Comment: Thanks all for the explanation, but the `import` example was just an illustration. (And apparently not a very good one...)

Comment: @SilvioMayolo I never expected `import` to work (that's why I wrote "unsurprisingly"), it was just an illustration. I edited the question and removed that part. I think it's clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for **modules**, containing **functions**. See the Python Tutorial: [Modules](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html) and [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html#executing-modules-as-scripts). Regarding your specific points:

> 1. Know when a script is being called from another script and when it's run directly

For that, you want [`if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/4518341). In the example below, I'll use it in each file.

- Related question: [What does if __name__ == "__main__": do?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/419163/4518341)

> 2. Be able to get information/variables from the parent script into the child script.

For that, the functions can take [arguments](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-argument). In the example below, I'll use an argument representing the calling module.

---

`mwe1.py`

```
def foo(caller):
    print(__name__, caller)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    foo('mwe1')
```

`mwe2.py`

```
def bar(caller):
    print(__name__, caller)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    bar('mwe2')
```

`mwe0.py`

```
import mwe1
import mwe2

def main():
    print(__name__)

    mwe1.foo('mwe0')
    mwe2.bar('mwe0')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Running each of them:

```
In [1]: %run mwe0.py
__main__
mwe1 mwe0
mwe2 mwe0

In [2]: %run mwe1.py
__main__ mwe1

In [3]: %run mwe2.py
__main__ mwe2
```